# What elements are affected when dehydrated?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, dehydration

I know that the blood vessels constrict and there is a decrease in water in the blood. Are there any other elements that increase or decrease when the human body is dehydrated?

Comment: When you say "element" what do you mean? It isn't clear from your question, because it seems like you're saying that water is an element, which it isn't (except I suppose in mythology). What efforts have you made to answer this elsewhere? e.g. [does this page answer your question](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK555956/)?